# The same iris animation than the iphone photo application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation

I would like to have exactly the same iris animation than the original photo app of the iphone.

Now I use this:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.duration = 1.5;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
                                functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.type = @"cameraIris";
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

It's working but it's not exactly the same animation. The view of the iris should come from the bottom and then the iris should open. With my code, I just have the Iris which appear in the center and open.

Answer (score 0):

you should add an extra view on your content view,and then

```
[extraView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

in the animation complete block ,call

```
[extraView removeFromSuperView];
```